# Why don't the SPFx web parts below the first one load on a page?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

Is there a way to make sure all the content, or at least the first few web parts on a page load right away?

I have a SharePoint Online classic view page that has four different custom SPFX web parts. Only the first one loads on the page when you first go there. This leaves a lot of white space which gives the appearance that this is all the content on the page.

[image]

Then after you scroll a little bit the second one appears.

[image]

Comment: It could be that SPFx incorrectly detects the amount of white space on the page. Have you tried testing it with different heights of the header image to see if it has any effect?

Comment: If I make the browser larger or shrink the height of the banner image the item below will display on page load. SharePoint or SPFx is making a calculation on what to display on the page. This calculation is incorrect for my purposes when the page is not tall enough. My question is: How to turn this off or change it?

Comment: I don't think you can turn it off or control it at the moment, but I'd suggest you submit an issue on GitHub at https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues where SharePoint engineers could review it and hopefully fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6091). It describes a similar issue, custom SPFx web parts that won't load due to lazy load. Scrolling the page helps as well as using a #dummyanchor that does not exist on the page in the url. The GitHub issue does mention that this should be resolved for Dynamic Data web parts.